# Win10, VirtualBox,Ubuntu, Vue-cli 3 - watching not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vagrant, virtual-machine, vue-cli-3

I cloned project from github and deployment on VM.
All works fine except watching if any file in project updating.
VagrantFile have string to syn folder

```
config.vm.synced_folder './', '/app', owner: 'vagrant', group: 'vagrant'
```

Tried to add vue.config.js with

```
module.exports = {
 configureWebpack: {
  devServer: {
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: ['node_modules'],
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1500
    },
    public: '192.168.83.181' // vagrant machine address
   }
  }
}
```

Below how project structure and terminal with executed `vue-cli-service build --watch --mode development` looks

[image]

```
node --version
v8.12.0
vue --version
3.1.3
```

Tried on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 versions.

Comment: Have you installed `inotify-tools`? You need that package installed on Ubuntu to watch file changes. Just run `sudo apt install inotify-tools` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Not helped. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I think the problem is not relative to vue-cli. Because if you change your js code in vm with vi. Then vue-cli can watch this change and pre-compile.But with change from win 10. nothing to happen, despite of changing code is reflected on share folder

Comment: So you don't actually have an answer / a solution for it?

Comment: The temporary solution is re-run vue-cli build command everytime you want see changes code